# remove animation after scrolling

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove an animation after scrolling to the top position. how can I remove this animation? 
do i need a `setTimeout` function? or can I use the other function?

```
window.onscroll = function () {
scrollFunction()
};


function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("topButton").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("topButton").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function topFunction(ID, btn) {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById(ID);
    var animation = btn;
    animation.classList.add('rotate');
    elmnt.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    if (document.body.scrollTop == 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0) {
        animation.classList.remove('rotate')
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you use `removeEventListener()` ??

Comment: addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction)
and when it reaches the top
removeEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable or class on some element to detect when an animation is done.

For example:

```
var isAnimated = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (!isAnimated) {
    scrollFunction();
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll');
  }
}

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("topButton").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        isAnimated = true;
        document.getElementById("topButton").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```